# Help identify "0GSV" or "OGSV" SMD Integrated Circuit

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

This IC is part of a malfunctioning LCD LED backlight control circuit built around the D60A60. Maybe it's a voltage regulator? Couldn't find after many tries. The marking is either OGSV or 0GSV.
[image: SMD IC]

Comment: It could be one of TI's many small switched voltage converters, they tend to have obscure markings and ~6 legs, give or take. See for example [TPS62230](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS62230) which is a fairly close match, marking OG but 6 pins. Though if so I'd expect to see a coil somewhere near. A better pic covering more of the surrounding parts would be helpful.

Comment: In the end, the D60A60 was the culprit of the problems in the circuit. The "0GSV" seems to be some voltage regulator, with an steady voltage output but no coils are connected to it.